# Is there any way to add tags to the <head> section in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I develop a plugin and need to add meta tags to the  section.

I have spent about 1 hour and had found a lot of hooks, but all of them are bypasses. I don't want to turn my code in piece of ****, can sb tell me if there is normal way to add html to the ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which kind of content you want to include in `<head>`.

**Scripts and styles** need to be registered and/or enqueued using the proper WP functions:

- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)
- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

You can hook this functions in [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) if you need them in your front-end (as I guess from your question) or [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to have them available in admin area.

Any **other type of content** could be hooked up using the [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action hook:

```
function hook_metatag() {
    ?>
    <meta name="description" content="Description">
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_metatag');
```

This will be echoed when the theme calls the `wp_head()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The standard is to use the [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) hook.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    echo '<meta ... />';
} );
```

***Note:*** This works well for meta tags. However, if you're injecting styles or scripts, instead of printing those out yourself using `wp_head`, use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) or [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).